# Asp.net Core Datetime parameter gets wrong date format while passing from view via ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, datetime, asp.net-core

I need to send 01/09/2017 (dd/MM/yyyy) this date from view to methods. The URL shows what i sent but i got that date in methods parameter like "09 Jan 2017". What should i do? Please suggest.

```
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
                        opts =>
                        {
                            var supportedCultures = new[]
                            {
                               new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
                            };

                    opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("de-DE");
                    opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                    opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
                        });
```

I have added this in ConfigureService(startup.cs). Still not working.. Tried with "de-US", "de-UK" format.

Comment: Do not send it has local format, the best way is to use ISO format **YYYY-MM-DD**. If you need to display it has local use the DateTime methods or moment if you work with JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

When I send dates from a view to an action (usually via jquery POST), I convert it to a ulong epoch time (Since Jan 1 1970) using javascript Date.getTime(). My javascript times are all UTC, which allows me to use the following extension methods on my server:

```
public static ulong ToJavascriptTicks(this DateTime t)
{
    return (ulong)(t.ToUniversalTime() - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds;
}
public static DateTime FromJavascriptTicks(this DateTime t, ulong ticks)
{
    return new DateTime(0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddMilliseconds(ticks).Add(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) - DateTime.MinValue).ToLocalTime();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution to this question.
I posted date-time as string value (client to controller) and then converted it to date-time. 
It solved my problem. But a better solution will be appreciated.